# Python yerr bars every ten samples

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

My problem is that I have a **bar plot** in which I have from 100 to 500 elements in X, and if I put *yerr* in each one it turns out prety ugly.

What I want to do is to put the *yerr bars* every ten elements (for example: the first element of x has the yerr bars, but from 2 to 9 don't; then, 10 has, but 11 to 19 don't... and so on).

You know some way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do it.

- First, you have to change the type of graph, from bars to normal (a line
  plot: pyplot.plot()).
- Then, when setting the errors, there's a parameter called
  *errorevery=z* which lets you put error bars every *z* samples.